# Container div and overflow issues

Tags: html, overflow, css-float, css

OK, so I have an internal div that is designed to contain text, images, etc.
The images are floated in this instance.
After the internal div is a footer, which is my problem. No matter what I try, the internal div won't expand around the images and hence, the footer won't sit below the images.

The example can be seen here: http://baradineholdings.com.au/about2.php

```
#internal
{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#row {
    min-width: 480px;
    display: block;
}

#movers-row {
    margin: -406px 0 0 121px;
}

#movers-row div {
    width: 49.9%;
    float: left;
}

#movers-row div img {
    float: right;
} 

#footer {
    width: 960px;
    height: 98px;
    border-top: 1px outset #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Someone has probably answered it, but I don't seem to be searching using the right terms so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your css of this id..

```
#footer {
 width: 960px;
 height: 98px;
 border-top: 1px outset #ccc;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: white;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}
```

**Update:** Change this id's css as well.. works on Chrome.. on linux,so.. havnt tested it on IE9

```
#movers-row {
 margin: -406px 0 0 121px;
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter .. ?? please care to comment?? .. the footer was not placed properly.. with `float:left` and `position:relative` added -- things are inplace now.. used firebug on the link provided to change the code.. only once i confirmed the working of the edits that i have proposed did i asnwer the question!!.. unless there is something wrong here -- the downvote seems pointless!!

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter...but that said, I've tried your fix and it doesn't render properly in IE9 or Chrome 17...thanks for trying :)

Comment: @fizzBuzz updated the code.. Change the css as specified.. it should work on Chrome 17..

Comment: Ahh brilliant! Works in both Chrome and IE now!
Can you explain why I need height: auto; and overflow: hidden; ?

Comment: @FizzBuzz  if you has seen the height of `movers-row` using firebug/chrome's dev tool -- you would've realized its height is `0`.. that means,that div is not encompassing its children which has a defined height.. hence,`height:auto` enables dynamic height for `movers-row` and adding `overflow:hidden` enables the parent to encompass the child div.. in the sence the parent contains the child..

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a *clearfix* to that container so it expands to the same height as it's children. It's better done as a css class selector so you can re-use it on different elements.

Try this one from the html5 Boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/html5boilerplate-site/built/en_US/docs/css/#clearfix-

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; clear: both;}
```

Comment: Hrmm, so I added the .clearfix code to my CSS (literally copied and pasted what you posted here) and this line of code <div id="internal clearfix"> to my page, still doesn't render properly in Chrome 17 or IE9

Comment: Didn't you say the collapsed div is the #footer element? So it should be applied to this instead: `<div id="footer" class="clearfix">`

Comment: Also, just had a look at your example and your #movers-row div has a -400px top margin which is screwing up your layout. You'll need to fix the images inside that by floating them and ensuring the sum of their widths including padding and margins does not exceed the width of the container

Comment: Nah, you need the -400px top margin;
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/23/ask-sm-equal-spacing-css-image-replacement-max-side-on-images/

Comment: No, you don't. You've copied markup designed for a fluid width layout and stuck it into a fixed layout without understanding the original author's intention. Bah, if it works for you, fine...